# Shift data column-wise

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with date columns, an example:

```
a           b           c           d           e  
            09-09-2015  09-08-2015              09-12-2015
09-08-2015              09-11-2015  09-12-2015  
09-08-2015              09-11-2015              09-12-2015
09-08-2015  09-09-2015              09-11-2015  09-12-2015
09-08-2015  09-09-2015  09-10-2015  09-11-2015  09-12-2015
```

Is there a way how I could create a new table where all date values are shifted to the left, so there are no gaps? For my data that would be:

```
a           b           c           d           e  
09-09-2015  09-08-2015  09-12-2015
09-08-2015  09-11-2015  09-12-2015  
09-08-2015  09-11-2015  09-12-2015
09-08-2015  09-09-2015  09-11-2015  09-12-2015
09-08-2015  09-09-2015  09-10-2015  09-11-2015  09-12-2015
```

Sample data:

```
-- drop table if exists tst;

create table tst (
    a date,
    b date,
    c date,
    d date,
    e date);

insert into tst values 
    (NULL, current_date + 1, current_date, NULL, current_date + 4),
    (current_date, NULL, current_date + 3, current_date + 4, NULL),
    (current_date, NULL, current_date + 3, NULL, current_date + 4),
    (current_date, current_date + 1, NULL, current_date + 3, current_date + 4),
    (current_date, current_date + 1, current_date + 2, current_date + 3, current_date  + 4)     
    ;
```

I thought it would work with simple update:

```
update tst set a = case when a is not null then a else
            case    when b is not null then b
                when c is not null then c
                when d is not null then d
                when e is not null then e end
            end;
```

This is not a way, because with column `b` I would need to handle the situation where the value has been moved to `a` previously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's ok to create a new table, you could transform each row of `tst` into a row which just contains an array of dates. Then you could remove `NULL`s with `array_remove(anyarray, NULL)` and fill a new table with the resulting array.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW tst_array AS
    SELECT
        array_remove(ARRAY[a,b,c,d,e], NULL) AS dates
    FROM
        tst;

SELECT
    dates[1] AS a,
    dates[2] AS b,
    dates[3] AS c,
    dates[4] AS d,
    dates[5] AS e
FROM
    tst_array;
```

Comment: This is very cool. When I lasted worked with PostgreSQL there was no `array_remove()`.

Comment: @TomasGreif: `array_remove` was introduced in 9.3